# Is there an Drag/Drop Cancelled Event in WinRT?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-runtime

im looking for an Drag/Drop cancelled event in Metro, this means if the user drags an item and drops it outside of an droppable area.

how can i achieve this or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not found such an event (for c#/XAML)! Perhaps (hopefully) an event will exists in the final release!

As a temporary workaround, I have registered to the `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerReleased`-event.
On drag start then, I set a boolean indicator to true, and if drag ends, the `PointerReleased`-event will be fired and I can test for the boolean indicator.

**Workaround**
In the constructor of the Page (or whatever element) register to PointerReleased:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerReleased+=CoreWindow_PointerReleased;
```

The eventhandler could look somehow like this:

```
void CoreWindow_PointerReleased(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args) {
     if (m_isDragging) {
           m_isDragging = false;
           // Here you know that a drag-operation came to a end
     }
}
```

And the indicator you can set for example as follows;

```
    private void Entries_DragStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e){            
        m_isDragging = true;
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude,
instead of capturing pointer released  on the whole page
you can register "pointer capture lost" on the listview or the item that you drag, i believe it fires less times at least :D

```
 listView_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e){
//do the logic you want;
}
```